# NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler - how to clear collection

Tags: silverlight, csv, gps

I am working with this sample: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ef6a80c07fb84f84a5fe5192221f582c
specifically with “GraphicsDataSourcesDemo”, which uses Silverlight API.
It allow for loading csv file with Lat Long coordinates, which are displayed as points on the map. In my own application I successfully implemented part about displaying points, but I have problem with a Clear button (which is not implemented in the included sample code). Since `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `StreamReader` are used, standard method like:

```
private void GPSClearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = Map.Layers["data"] as GraphicsLayer;
  graphicsLayer.ClearGraphics();            
}
```

does not work.

I would appreciate any advice on how to make displayed points disappear from my map (after user decide so by clicking a button Clear).

Answer (score 0):

The graphical elements merely represent data items, so either you want to throw away the data items (that's what I understand from an action called 'Clear') or you want to 'hide' the displayed data items and later be able to 'show' them again. Only the latter one is to be solved in the View/GraphicsLayer. The former one means you have to 'Clear' the list of data items i.e. coordinates, and (if used correctly) the bindings from View to the DataContext will ensure that all corresponding visual elements are removed from the UI.

So you will need something like this:

```
public class CoordinateCollectionViewmodel
{
    public ICommand Clear { get; set; } // setup to call Coordinates.Clear()
    public ObservableCollection Coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have never worked before with Observable Collections, so I have no idea where and how attach a code, which you proposed. Could you give me more detailed answer?